# Can PUBLIC attributes and methods (that work on public attributes) be considered as encapsulation?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, encapsulation

Consider a simple example:

```
class encap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr=100

    def get_attr(self):
        print(self.attr)

obj=encap()
obj.get_attr()
```

Please note, here we are are not making an attribute private but still it is bound within a class and we have a method to access it.

My question is:

1. considering the fact that encapsulation refers to bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, **can the above example still represent encapsulation concept of OOP even though we haven't made the attribute private?**
2. Encapsulation is used to hide the values or state of a structured data object inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them. **Therefore, is making the attribute private mandatory to justify encapsulation?**

Comment: There is no way to enforce "private" in Python. But you can establish the convention that if something is to be private then everyone respects it. Place a single `_` as attribute prefix. Or a double `__` if you want "privateness" really bad. Disrespecting the convention can break the code that uses your code (client-code) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation means certain attributes and certain operations are conceptually related to each other. So, you encapsulated `encap` object.
And You want to say about a information hiding. 
Good SW Design achieves high maintainability and modifiability.Information hiding helps it by hiding details and providing important interfaces only.

By your questions,

1. Yes. it still represents encapsulation.
2. No. But you make it a better sw design by hiding information, if you make it private.

Looking into your code, you define an attribute as public and define a setter interface too. This attribute will be able to be accessed by 2 paths. So decide whether you change attribute to private or remove setter interface.

Comment: Note that as in Python the attributes are public, they can be accessed directly using dot notation on the object, so coding setters and getters is less common than for example in Java. Make that only when you want some degree of attribute protection or side-effect processing on access. Defining a Python property can help then.